# How can we change base url of localhost without using virtual host technique (on wamp)

Tags: php, apache

can we change base url local host with out using virtual host technique.
for example my current base url is:
localhost/project
and my desire url is
abc/project
on local host can any one answer as soon as possible

Comment: why do you want abc on your local machine?

Comment: yes jogesh_pi
i am working on already exiting project the previous developer was doing something like this he did not configure virtual host and changing base url of localhost instead of localhost he was using abc

Comment: the main thing is he hard code the url and it is big project so currently i have to run this as it is then i will change hard coding to dynamic coding but currently short of time i have to do this is there is any way jogesh_pi

Comment: for my projects i checked the localhost environment and generate the url according to, and if localhost environment not found then generate the original url.

Comment: yup i did that same thing but previous developer did not change httd.conf file , did not change the system32 host file , did not make a virtual host . so i am confuse from where he did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your hosts file on your own machine. You can make a pointer from  to  thus ensuring your computer will look for  on your own machine. Next step is to configure  in your vhost.

For instance you could change your hosts file so `google.com` would be pointing to `localhost`. Once you type `google.com` in your browser it would try to server a website from your own machine.

Please note that only you (with the changed hostname) will see the website.

See: [How to setup the hosts file for multiple domains/hosts with the same ip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505835/how-to-setup-the-hosts-file-for-multiple-domains-hosts-with-the-same-ip)

Comment: Luceos i know this configuration but dear friend i got one already exiting project in which previous developer replace url with out changing system 32 host file, with out creating virtual host.

is there is any other way to do that work

Comment: Not on localhost, no. If you have fixed IP on your localhost, you can point your domain through proper DNS settings to your localhost. You then don't need a hosts-file change. However, then, the localhost website would be publicly available, served from your (slow) localhost connection.

Comment: Luceos thanks for answer plus you can access localhost with your system name

Answer (score 0):

if you face problem like that, some one is using abc instead of local host then you check your system 32 host file or see the setting of virtual host. If there is no change in these files regarding to your url then start forward check your computer name because you can access your localhost via your computer name as well.

Answer (score -1):

open c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache[version]\conf\httpd.conf, and set your new path:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/abc/project"
```

Comment: he's talking about base URL, not documentroot.

Comment: moin in that case we also type a local host i do not want to type local host just want to replace localhost with abc