# How to use Multiple xampp Like xampp php version 5, xampp php version 7, version 8. I also install it but problem new laravel project npm not install

Tags: php, laravel, npm, xampp, laravel-jetstream

when i run xampp php version 7  all are good but when i run xampp php version 8 but my current project not work [this is my laravel 9 xampp php version 8 current project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5DW7.png)

and another problem when i run new project and install npm install && npm run dev but it's not work
[npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAAQq.png) 
and when I run npm run dev this result [npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6abd.png)

and when I run php artisan migrate and serve after then [login url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF9dv.png)

Comment: I would recommend **laragon** if you need multiple php version. It is so easy to switch other php version.
Here is the link https://laragon.org/

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp)

Answer (score 4):

### Why switch between PHP versions when you can use *multiple PHP versions* at the same time with *a single xampp installation*?

**With a single xampp installation, you have 2 options:**

1. **Run an older PHP version for only the directory of your old project:** This will serve the purpose most of the time. You may have one or two old projects that you intend to run with an older PHP version. Just configure xampp to run an older PHP version for only those project directories.
2. **Run an older PHP version on a separate port of xampp:** Sometimes you may be upgrading an old project to the latest PHP version and at the same time you need to run the same project back and forth between the new PHP version and the old PHP version. To do this you can set an older PHP version on a different port (say 8056) so when you go to `http://localhost/any_project/`, xampp runs PHP 7 and when you go to `http://localhost:8056/any_project/` xampp runs PHP 5.6.
3. **Run an older PHP version on a virtualhost:** You can create a virtualhost like localhost56 to run PHP 5.6 while you can use PHP 7 on localhost.

### Lets set it up

**Step 1:** Download PHP

So you have PHP 7 running under xampp, you want to add an older PHP version to it (say PHP 5.6). Download the nts (Non Thread Safe) version of the PHP zip archive from [php.net](http://php.net/downloads.php) (see [archive](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/) for older versions) and extract the files under `c:\xampp\php56`. The thread safe version does not include php-cgi.exe.

**Step 2:** Configure `php.ini`

Open the file `c:\xampp\php56\php.ini` in notepad. If the file does not exist, copy `php.ini-development` to `php.ini` and open it in notepad. Then uncomment the following line:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Also if the following line exists in Apache config `httpd-xampp.conf`

```
SetEnv PHPRC "\\path\\to\\xampp\\php"
```

comment it out with with a leading # (hash character).

**Step 3:** Configure apache

Open xampp control panel, click the config button for apache, and click `Apache (httpd-xampp.conf)`. A text file will open. Put the following settings at the bottom of the file:

```
ScriptAlias /php56 "C:/xampp/php56"
Action application/x-httpd-php56-cgi /php56/php-cgi.exe
<Directory "C:/xampp/php56">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

***Note:*** *You can add more versions of PHP to your xampp installation following step 1 to 3 if you want.*

**Step 4 (option 1):** *[Add Directories to run a specific PHP version]*

Now you can set directories that will run in PHP 5.6. Just add the following at the bottom of the config file (`httpd-xampp.conf` from Step 3) to set directories.

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_old_project1">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_old_project2">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

**Step 4 (option 2):** *[Run an older PHP version on a separate port]*

Now to to set PHP v5.6 on port 8056, add the following code to the bottom of the config file (`httpd-xampp.conf` from Step 3).

```
Listen 8056
<VirtualHost *:8056>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 4 (option 3):** *[Run an older PHP version on a virtualhost]*

To create a virtualhost (localhost56) on a directory (htdocs56) to use PHP v5.6 on http://localhost56, create directory htdocs56 at your desired location and
add localhost56 to your hosts file ([see how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893591)),
then add the following code to the bottom of the config file (`httpd-xampp.conf` from Step 3).

```
<VirtualHost localhost56:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs56"
    ServerName localhost56
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs56">
        Require all granted    
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Finish:** Save and Restart Apache

Save and close the config file. Restart apache from the xampp control panel. If you went for option 2, you can see the additional port(8056) listed in your xampp control panel.

[image: xampp control panel showing apache running with configured ports]

For more information, take a look at this thread: [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp)

Comment: Amazing answer. I just want to add something to Step 4 (option 3). It is also possible to put the   
 <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
in your httpd-vhosts.conf instead of in httpd-xampp.conf. That way you have direct control on a project by project basis and can point local URLs like http://oldproject.loc to a project running PHP 5.6, while http://newproject.loc could point to a project running another PHP version as defined in step 3.

Comment: I'd recommend to not install other PHP versions from php.net. Rather I'd recommend to download other XAMPP bundles from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/ and use the PHP folder from the XAMPP bundle. The benefit of this is that you will have matching default values for php.ini between the versions.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the answer from @munim-munna in 2018. See the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586592/8016720 Do not copy someone else's answer. Instead mark the question as a duplicate and reference the answer you copied.